# Is there any dataset of Indian Traffics Signs?

Tags: data-request, traffic, india, classification

I wanted data set of Indian Traffic Sign for classification purpose.

Answer (score 2):

I would do a google search "[road signs India](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=indian%20traffic%20sign%20images)". I found this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Road_signs_in_India) had some clear pictures with descriptions in English. If you want Hindi or other language translation, I suspect a google image search will help.